# Does Azure YAML pipelne support wildcards in path filter in trigger?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have this structure of projects (folders) in git repository:

```
/src
/src/Sample.Backend.Common
/src/Sample.Backend.Common.Tests
/src/Sample.Backend.Common.Domain
/src/Sample.Backend.Common.Domain.Tests
/src/Sample.Backend.Pricing.Abstractions
/src/Sample.Backend.Pricing.Domain
/src/Sample.Backend.Pricing.Domain.Tests
/src/Sample.Backend.Pricing.Persistence
/src/Sample.Backend.Pricing.Persistence.Tests
/src/Sample.Backend.Accounting.Abstractions
/src/Sample.Backend.Accounting.Domain
/src/Sample.Backend.Accounting.Domain.Tests
/src/Sample.Backend.Accounting.Persistence
/src/Sample.Backend.Accounting.Persistence.Tests
/src/Sample.Backend.Api
/src/Sample.Common
/src/Sample.Frontend.Common
/src/Sample.Frontend.Web
/src/Sample.Tests.Common
```

*(The sample is simplified, in real there are much more projects/folders.)*

I want different pipelines for different parts. For example a pipeline to be triggered whenever any file is commited in `master` branch in **any Backend** project. Something like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - src/Sample.Backend.*
    - src/Sample.Common
    - src/Sample.Tests.Common
```

The problem is, that filter `src/Sample.Backend.*` is not working. I have to add exact name of each Backend folder to get it working. I could use `exclude` but I have the same problem - there are many other projects and I would have to name them all.

I found that wildcards are not supported: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/397#issuecomment-422958966

Is there any other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 5):

> Does Azure YAML pipelne support wildcards in path filter in trigger?

This is a known request on our main forum for product:

[Support wildcards (*) in Trigger > Path Filters](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366363/support-wildcards-in-trigger-path-filters-1.html)

This feature has not yet been implemented; you could add your comment and vote this on user voice.

**As a workaround** for us, we add an inline PowerShell task as the **first** task to execute the git command line `git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only` then get the modified file names and filter the files name in the latest submit, and use [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to sets variables which are then referenced in custom conditions in the next steps in the build pipeline:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['CustomVar'], 'True'))
```

Our inline PowerShell script:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

$editedFiles = git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only

echo "$($editedFiles.Length) files modified:"

$editedFiles | ForEach-Object {
   echo $_
    Switch -Wildcard ($_ ) {
        'XXXX/Src/Sample.Backend.*' { 
              Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomVar]True")
         }        
        'XXXX/Src/Sample.Common*' { 
              Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomVar]True")}
        'XXXX/Src/Sample.Tests.Common' { 
              Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomVar]True")}

    }
}
```

Then add the condition for all remaining tasks:

[image]

In this case, if the changed files do not meet our filters, then all remaining tasks will be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: 09/09/2021**

This is possible now as it is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters)

> Wild cards can be used when specifying inclusion and exclusion branches for CI or PR triggers in a pipeline YAML file. However, they cannot be used when specifying path filters. For instance, you cannot include all paths that match src/app/**/myapp*. This has been pointed out as an inconvenience by several customers. This update fills this gap. Now, you can use wild card characters (**, *, or ?) when specifying path filters.

Note: documentation seems to be not updated yet.

**Old answer:**

No this is not possible at the moment. You have even feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366363/support-wildcards-in-trigger-path-filters-1.html) and I would recommend to upvote it. (I already did this) Rick in above mentioned topic shared his idea how to overcome the issue:

> I currently achieve this by having 3 files:
>
> - azure-pipelines.yml ( This calls some python on each commit )
> - azure-pipelines.py [(This checks for changed folders and has some parameters to ignore certain folders, then calls the API directly)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)
> - azure-pipelines-trigger.yml ( This is called by the python based on the changed folders )
>
> It works well enough, but it is unfortunate for the need to go through these loops.

But it needs an extra work.

Answer (score 1):

This feature will roll out over the next two to three weeks according to the latest [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#support-for-wild-cards-in-path-filters)

Comment: Have you had any luck with it? Its been 4 weeks now and its still not working for us.

Comment: There is an update in developercommunity thread https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-wildcards-in-trigger-path-filters-1/366363#T-N1546999

Answer (score 1):

Update on this.

It took a few weeks but the change mentioned by pavlo in the comments above finally got rolled out and path triggers are now supported in YAML.